# MongoDB C driver mongoc_collection_find() can't find Document by field

Tags: c++, c, mongodb

i try to find document by field name which is inside object .
i have this 1 document inside collection names "TestCollection"

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c2f0f3892b312e740041a1"),
    "Obj" : {
        "Type" : 0,
        "Num" : NumberLong(1111111111111)
    }
}
```

Based on this tutorial : http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/tutorial.html#find
And this API doc about "find" i learn that i need to use dot notation to search by  Obj.Num
I try to find this document like this :

```
mongoc_collection_t *collection  = NULL;
mongoc_cursor_t *cursor  = NULL;
const bson_t *doc  = NULL;
char *str = NULL;
bson_t * query = bson_new ();
std::string str;
bool b = BSON_APPEND_INT64(query,"TestCollection.Num",1111111111111);
// b is true
collection = mongoc_client_get_collection(m_mogoClient,"CollectionDB","Obj.Num");
cursor = mongoc_collection_find (collection, MONGOC_QUERY_NONE, 0, 0, 0, query, NULL, NULL);




 while (mongoc_cursor_next (cursor, &doc)) {
             //it is never gets here to print the document 
             str = bson_as_json (doc, NULL);
             printf ("%s\n", str);
             bson_free (str);
}

bson_destroy (query);
mongoc_cursor_destroy (cursor);
mongoc_collection_destroy (collection);
```

to test the query i run it in the mongoDB shell 
and i did get back the document result as you see :

```
> use CollectionDB
switched to db CollectionDB
> db
Collection
> db.TestCollection.find(
... {
... "Obj.Num":1111111111111
... }
... )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56c2f0f3892b312e740041a1"), "Obj" : { "Type" : 0, "Num" : NumberLong("1111111111111") } }

>
```

what is wrong in the c code , why it is not giving me back result ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool b = BSON_APPEND_INT64(query,"Obj.Num",1111111111111);
collection = mongoc_client_get_collection(m_mogoClient,"CollectionDB","TestCollection");
cursor = mongoc_collection_find (collection, MONGOC_QUERY_NONE, 0, 0, 0, query, NULL, NULL);
```

Hopefully you figured it out by now.

the dot notation in bson b (line1) needs to be the namespace of the field

the Collection name (line 2 & referenced in your shell code) was mashup of the collection name and the namespace.  It should be contain the database name and the collection name only.